# Добавление пользователей в список telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграм бота, проблема конкретно в маленьком кусочке кода:

```
        list_of_players = []
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Теперь вы участвуете в розыгрыше с id = {0}'.format(rId)) #rId - переменная с id розыгрыша, созданная в другой функции
        list_of_players.append(message.chat.username)
```

В присоединении к розыгрышу проблем нет, любой пользователь знающий id спокойно присоединяется. Проблема заключается в том, что когда к розыгрышу присоединяется второй человек, первый из списка удаляется, и по итогу в розыгрыше всегда остается один участник, как исправить?

Comment: скиньте болье кода, а вообще мне кажется, что вы просто каждый раз объявляете список `list_of_players`, попробуйте вынести его за функцию

Comment: Хах, и правда, вынес список за функцию - все наладилось, глупая ошибка вышла, спасибо!